# Access 2010 PDF, Save and Email a Report Using VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using Access 2010 and found the Send to Email as PDF command indispensable. However, I have a problem in that I've hidden the main ribbon from my users which means they can't actually click that button.

Can anyone tell me the VBA code that will let me PDF, save the file and email via Gmail an individual report based on a given unique ID? I am happy for the user to add the email address, subject and message body and for them to click send.

I begin with the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
Dim myPath As String
Dim strReportName As String

DoCmd.OpenReport "rptsuivi", acViewPreview, , "tblsuivi.[N°Suivi] = '" & Me.[CompanyName] & "' "

myPath = "C:\"
strReportName = "Raport de suivi" + "-" + ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, acFormatPDF, , myPath + strReportName, True
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptsuivi"
```

Comment: do you have to use Gmail only? Can you use Outlook?

Comment: yes i can use both

Comment: the only thing that I cannot understand is what will be in the pdf report? Is it a specific table in your access database? You can create a pdf report from access tables and send it as an attachment via outlook easily. Also, you can populate the fields in outlook if you already know that. Plus, how are you going to run the macro? do you want to use a button or you want to run it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you can create a macro that just runs the ribbon command

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx

http://www.ribboncreator2010.de/Onlinehelp/EN/_2el0osmon.htm

you'll need to find the right idMso for the ribbon function you're trying to use.

```
Sub SendToEmailAsPDF()

Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FileSendAsAttachment"

End Sub
```